# Order of deferred jquery ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have list of language, `['en', 'de']` and so on and i want to take complex ajax request for every language. On first ajax request i get intents quantity foк every language.

```
var languages = ['en', 'de', 'es', 'fr', 'it', 'cn'];
intents_dic = [];
chart_quantity = ['quantity'];
for (var x = 0; x < languages.length; x++){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
        for (i in data){
            intents_dic.push(data[i]['id'])
        }
        var intents_count = 0;
        var deferreds = [];
```

And on the second step i need to count phrases quantity for every intent from previous call. I use deferred list for this task.

```
for (var id = 0; id < intents_dic.length; id++){
    deferreds.push($.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data){
        intents_count += data['templates'].length;
        }
    }))
}
$.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function() {
    chart_quantity.push(intents_count);
})
```

But when deferred ajax requests are complete, the order of completion differs with language list order (it's principal for building diagram). Can this problem be fixed, or it's a feature of ajax calls? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's a feature.

Comment: Don't use `async:false`!

Comment: @Bergi is it better to use closure instead of sync requests?

Comment: If by "closure" you mean "asynchronous callbacks", then yes - sync requests are nothing but trouble.

Comment: @Bergi By closure i mean this example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KS6q5/). It allows to use async calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your forked and thus working jsfiddle (asynchronous calls with ordered results).

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    setTimeout(function(x){
        done(x,results);
    }(i),1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/htuz3t3m/2/

Comment: Callbacks are important in jQuery.